# How to spyOn a static class method with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, class, static, jasmine, spy

I have a class with a static method that I want to test in Jasmine. I understand that static methods are not callable on instances of the class. So besides the fact that it cannot find the method to `spyOn`, my test does not pass, but how would one go about testing static methods in a class with *Jasmine*?

```
class Foo {
    static foobar (a, b) {
      return a * b
    }
}
```

Jasmine Test

```
it ('should test a static method', () => {
    let foo = new Foo()
    spyOn(foo, 'foobar')
    foo.foobar(2,3)
    expect(foo.foobar).toBe(6)
})
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You should be able to use `spyOn(Foo, 'foobar')` to make it a spy.

Also spies are not intended to directly be tested - they are a tool so that you can test other code more deterministically and in isolation.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that. Also, thanks for the clarification on how to use a spy :)